# How do I setup and load a cog into discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use the built-in help command in the discord.py commands extension but I can't seem to load a cog though so I can sort the commands. Here's my current code:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='fd!', description=description, intents=intents)

class Testing(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self._last_member = None
  
  @commands.command(description = "Sends a test message")
  async def test(ctx):
    await message.channel.send("Test")

#extra code for other un-grouped commands here

def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(Testing(bot))

#bot.run stuff here
```

Am I missing something? When I run the command (fd!test) it says the command doesn't exist and when I run fd!help it isn't listed and neither is the cog.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to add `import discord` and `from discord.ext import commands` at the top of your cog file. Make sure you have your cog files in a folder called `cogs` which should be in the same folder as the rest of your project. In your main code, add this to actually load the cog:

```py
# loading all cogs
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

Also, you need to pass in `self` before `ctx`, and you need to change `message.channel.send` to `ctx.send`:

```py
@commands.command(description = "Sends a test message")
  async def test(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("Test")
```

Comment: This has worked almost perfectly, when I try to run the test command, it says that 'callback for test command is missing 'ctx' parameter' and when I try fd!help test it says 'ValueError: Missing context parameter'. Any ideas?

Comment: @finalerock44 In your `test` command, try `await ctx.send("Test")` instead of `await message.channel.send("Test")`

Comment: didn't seem to work, printed the same errors as before

Comment: @finalerock44 Oh wait, in your `test` command, try to pass in `self` before `ctx`, like this: `async def test(self, ctx):`